# Rendering the nbsp issue of the XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

this is my Xml format

```
    <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Washington,</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">D.C. 20549</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"> 
</SPAN>
```

ad i am rendring it through the the XSLT file to print it but its throwing a error while parsing the `&nbsp;`

i googled..there are various ways which edit's the  XSLT to do this but is there any code snippet which can be used in the `JS` for this purpose because my XML is not fixed its dynamic and i think its a difficult task to add those lines in every XML file.

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_xml_content_string() 
{
                        xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        xmldoc.async = false;
                        xmldoc.load("book.xml");
                         xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                         xsldoc.async = false;
                         xsldoc.load("try.xsl");
                         ex= xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
                         document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = ex;

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What's the error it's throwing? Also, why would you do XSLT processing in the browser and not on the server?

Comment: its just not recognizing that text that &nbsp and after that it is not able to parse  the other text...

Comment: Include exact error messages in your questions, don't paraphrase them. You're just saying "it stops working there", which means people have to guess at what the cause is.

Comment: it just saying &nbsp is not recognized...
i mentioned in the comment

Comment: Error is `XML Parsing Error: undefined entity`

Comment: If you can read the file in memory, then you can perform a globl replace with JS -- my JS isn't strong, but I believe something like: `replace(theString, '/&nbsp;/&#xA0;/g')`

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should have DTD declaring the `&nbsp;`, because now your XML isn't a well-formed XML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE P [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xA0;">]>

<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Washington,</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">D.C. 20549</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">
    </SPAN>
</P>
```

Comment: hmmm i insert that line in my XML but i have many XML and its not possible to insert this line in all my XML... :(

thats y i want it to implemt through jscrpt

Comment: @Librak, I think you have 2 options: replace all `&nbsp;` with `&#xA0;` or define entity in your XML like in example above.

Comment: u mean to say using JS..
can u pls help me where to insert that replace all in my above javascipt code

Comment: @Librak You should replace the `&nbsp;` in the input files and whatever generates them, even if it's inconvenient. It's invalid XML, so it has no place being there in the first place, and hacking around this will just cause the problem agian when some othet code tries to read these files.